# Magento 2 - enable cash on delivery only for specific shipment method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, payment-methods

How to, for example, enable cash on delivery payment only when customer selected flat rate shipping method?

I cannot find a way doing this in shipment/payment configuration or in cart rules.

Answer (score 11):

I use an plugin in a custom module to set the `isAvailable()` function for `Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery` to false when shipping method `flatrate_flatrate` is selected.

file: `<magento-root>/app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Plugin/CashondeliveryPlug.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class CashondeliveryPlug
{
  /**
   * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
   */
   protected $_checkoutSession;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
   */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function aroundIsAvailable(
      \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $shippingMethod = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
        // $this->logger->debug($shippingMethod);

        if ($shippingMethod == 'flatrate_flatrate')
            return false;

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

file: `<magento-root>/app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplug" 
            type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\CashondeliveryPlug"
            disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Hope this helps you! Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: How to do this in backend

Comment: you have to make an custom module with an Plugin aroundIsAvailable function. You can't do this in the backend with stock-magento

Comment: this is my condition ...how to do this in backend

Comment: maybe you should open a new question, where you can give further information

Comment: Thank you so much @juhanix  i spend  more than 2 hours to find a flow. your solution help me lot. keep coding :)

Comment: I don't understand, how `aroundIsAvailable()` is called. It's new method (not override some method from `CashondeliveryPlug class`.

Comment: "A plugin, or interceptor, is a class that modifies the behavior of public class functions by intercepting a function call and running code before, after, or around that function call. This allows you to substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods for any class or interface.

Extensions that wish to intercept and change the behavior of a public method can create a Plugin class."

Comment: @divyasekar Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/323397/57334