# Payment method only admin Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment-methods, payment-gateway

When working with Magento 2, sometimes we want to disable Payment methods on the Front page and use it only for Admin. Or, if we want to set more rules for Payment methods to check whether payment method can be used. How we can do that?

Comment: you have declared sortOrder two times in di.xml.could you please remove it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144531)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should take a look at the payment abstract class `vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php`. We can see the method `public function isAvailable()` - This class will check whether payment method can be used.

```
   public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        if (!$this->isActive($quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null)) {
            return false;
        }

        $checkResult = new DataObject();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);

        // for future use in observers
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'payment_method_is_active',
            [
                'result' => $checkResult,
                'method_instance' => $this,
                'quote' => $quote
            ]
        );

        return $checkResult->getData('is_available');
    }
```

As can we see, there is an Observer event, like Magento 1, we can use Observer to disable our Payment Methods. It's Magento 1 way. However, Magento 2 introduces to developers [a new way - Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Create DI on front page:
**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module Name}/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod">
        <plugin name="testValidate"
                type="{Vendor}\{Module Name}\Plugin\Model\Method\Available" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module Name}/Plugin/Model/Method/Available.php**

```
<?php

namespace {Vender}\{Module Name}\Plugin\Model\Method;

class Available
{
   /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, $result)
    {

        if($subject->getCode() == 'your payment code, eg: cashondelivery') {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

`$subject` is the current Payment Method Model.

[image]

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: For reference, I found this answer helpful https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/41603

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/323397/57334 Thanks @Khoa TruongDinh