# Payment method in magento2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, plugin, php-7

How to disable the Cash on Delivery payment method in backend and frontend **Programmatically?**

Here the code I'm using:

> etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
    <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

Plugin:

```
public function aroundIsAvailable(
    \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    $quote = null
) {
    $result          = $proceed($quote);
    $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? "yes" : "no";
    if ($codAvailability == 'no') {
        return false;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**The actual problem is:** the quote is missed when plugin called from the frontend (checkout page).

Comment: did you get your solution?

Comment: @Ravindrasinh Zala answer is current please try that

Comment: i got it...But i  want to know about core flow................where to call isAvailable() method for showing available payment method list in core file

Comment: core file located at vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod.php

Comment: ill give path in my answer and if use for you please access it

Comment: yes....But i need .where to call isAvailable() in vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod.php

Comment: there is a function isAvailable in that file

Comment: yes.......it has quote....I can get pincode backend only from this quote...But i need it both ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple plugin on the method `isAvailable` of the model `Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\DisableCOD\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;

class DisableCashOnDelivery
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param BackendSession $backendSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        BackendSession $backendSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Cashondelivery $subject
     * @param                $result
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(Cashondelivery $subject, $result)
    {
        $condition = true; // Replace with your condition

        if ($condition) {
            return false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Just change the conditions to desired one.

The result on the frontend (checkout page):

[image: The result on the frontend]

The result on the backend (create new order page):

[image: The result on the backend]

Full plugin [could be found on github](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_DisableCOD)

#### Updated code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\DisableCOD\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutFrontendSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote as CheckoutBackendSession;

class DisableCashOnDelivery
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutFrontendSession|CheckoutBackendSession
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSession         $customerSession
     * @param BackendSession          $backendSession
     * @param CheckoutFrontendSession $checkoutFrontendSession
     * @param CheckoutBackendSession  $checkoutBackendSession
     * @param State                   $state
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        BackendSession $backendSession,
        CheckoutFrontendSession $checkoutFrontendSession,
        CheckoutBackendSession $checkoutBackendSession,
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->backendSession  = $backendSession;
        if ($state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
            $this->session = $checkoutBackendSession;
        } else {
            $this->session = $checkoutFrontendSession;
        }
    }

    public function aroundIsAvailable(
        \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($quote);
        if ($quote === null) {
            $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        }
        $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? 1 : 0;
        if (!$codAvailability) {
            return false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Do not forget add your classes to the di (`_pincodeModel`).

#### Update 2:

On the frontend the `$quote` argument is null because it was called from the method `\Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider::getConfig()` where the method `isAvailable()` of the each payment method was called without providing arguments, what means the `$quote` will be null:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $config = [];
    foreach ($this->methodCodes as $code) {
        if ($this->methods[$code]->isAvailable()) {
            $config['payment']['instructions'][$code] = $this->getInstructions($code);
        }
    }
    return $config;
}
```

But in the checkout session, it exists, and we can access it from the checkout session object.

#### Update 3:

For the backend the method `isAvailable()` of the all payment methods was called from the `Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Container::getMethods()` method which provides a quote in the arguments list:

```
/**
 * Retrieve available payment methods
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getMethods()
{
    $methods = $this->getData('methods');
    if ($methods === null) {
        $quote = $this->getQuote();
        $store = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;
        $methods = [];
        foreach ($this->getPaymentMethodList()->getActiveList($store) as $method) {
            $methodInstance = $this->getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()->create($method);
            if ($methodInstance->isAvailable($quote) && $this->_canUseMethod($methodInstance)) {
                $this->_assignMethod($methodInstance);
                $methods[] = $methodInstance;
            }
        }
        $this->setData('methods', $methods);
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

Here is why you can access the quote object from the backend directly, and can not do that on the frontend.

Comment: where to call isAvailable() method in core

Comment: In the class 'Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery'

Comment: $pinCode = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? "yes" : "no";
            if ($pinCode == 'no') {
                return false;
            }..........................its working for backend only

Comment: @PriyaM This plugin works for the backend and frontend. Could you update your question with actual conditions you are using?

Comment: .it has quote....I can get pincode backend only from this quote...But i need it both ends

Comment: @PriyaM Please, check updated code in my answer, I added quote detection.

Comment: if ($quote === null) {
            $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        }why quote is null for frontend

Comment: @PriyaM Please see my updated answer with clarification

Comment: getConfig() function for both front and backend?

Comment: @PriyaM See updated answer - update #3

Comment: @PriyaM The best way is using `$state->getAreaCode()` as in my example (see the `__construct` method).

Comment: its throw js error in checkout page

Comment: @PriyaM Could you add error body here?

Comment: TypeError: window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions is undefined

Comment: @PriyaM this error is not related to the code you added in the plugin. Check the place where you are using `checkoutConfig.payment.instructions` and try to detect why it is undefined (has no value).

Comment: I see the error and  also Place order button not showing in cod when the guest login .after reloading page is working fine.....if user is customer ,then its not return any error....

Comment: @PriyaM It's hard to say something without a full plugin code. :(

Comment: I have solved that error...........

Comment: how to show some massage in cod payment section

Comment: @PriyaM you should add it in the template (`.html`)

Comment: @PriyaM Please, ask a separate question, add code you are using inside and send me a link, I'll try to help :)

Comment: @PriyaM Sure, I'll try to clarify it for you when I'll have some free time.

Comment: This example not working on ONE STEP CHECKOUT.
Does anyone has example of that?

Answer (score 0):

Now this way disable payment method so please try COD ok

First you will need to create events.xml file under app/code/Company/Module/etc/. Then write “payment_method_is_active” event in it. This is the event which hits on checkout page for payment method availability.

> app/code/Company/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create PaymentMethodAvailable.php under Company/Module/Observer/ and write following code in the file. I am disabling the check money order payment method, you can change payment method code according to your need.

> app/code/Company/Module/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // you can replace "cashondelivery" with your required payment method code
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
}
```

Now the payment method Cash On Delivery  Order is disabled from checkout page

Comment: i need it for backend also

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130466/magento-2-how-do-i-programmatically-remove-payment-method

Comment: where to call isAvailable() method for showing available payment method list in core file