# How to hide COD payment method for specific product?

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.1.8, cash-on-delivery

I want to hide cash on delivery payment method for a specific product.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130466/magento-2-how-do-i-programmatically-remove-payment-method#answer-130594) and add a condition for checking product's SKU using the quote like this:

```
    use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

    /** @var CheckoutSession */
        protected $checkoutSession;

        /**
         * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
         */
        public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        }

        public function afterIsAvailable(Cashondelivery $subject, $result) {
    -------------
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
$products = $quote->getAllItems();
-----------------------
        }
```

check for sku and return `false`

Comment: it is not working, Checkout stops when using this module.

Comment: public function afterIsAvailable(Cashondelivery $subject, $result) {}

it is not working