# Magento 2 Checkout event issue

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, event-observer, product-list

I try to take the final product list after the checkout, so I create an observer for that.
I found a list of all dispatched events in Magento 2.1 which looks like this:

[dispatched-events](http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/)

I tried a lot of events, which is work properly, but nothing seems to work for the final checkout button.

I also tried `checkout_cart_save_after` but this event is before the final checkout button, and `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`but this event is not working.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or which event is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use the event `sales_order_place_after`. This event will work on final checkout (Place Order) button.

Get order data :

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
      $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();
      $proName[] = $item->getName(); // product name
 }
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // shipping address
$customer = $order->getCustomerId(); // using this id you can get customer name
```

Comment: so with this event i can obtain the final prodcut list?

Comment: @AlinLupoiu, Yes, This event will give you final order and its item list at the time of order placement.

Comment: and do you have any idea how to take the item list in my observer?

Comment: @AlinLupoiu, Check my updated answer

Comment: @AlinLupoiu, If this answer resolved the issue then mark as accepted so that other user will get help from this if they have similar issue.

Comment: one more question. where should i need to put the event.xml file. in etc/frontend folder  or in etc folder?

Comment: thank you very much man! you help me a lot! have a great day!

Comment: Are you using `\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer` ? I want to get shipping method but I get `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getShippingMethod() on null`

Comment: I use `payment_method_is_active` event to disable payment method.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716