# need to disable cash on delivery to particular cities(not country), using magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery, order-state

I am using magento 2. And I need to disable one payment method 'cash on delivery' to specific cities(not for countries).I found so many solutions but those are not meant for magento 2, I think those are for older versions.Because I couldn't find those files(or methods in the specified location) in my code. Can anyone help me ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new module and use a 'plugin' to add some logic to the `isAvailable` method of `Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery`.

Example plugin class:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;


use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class CashondeliveryPlug
{
    public function aroundIsAvailable(AbstractMethod $subject, callable $proceed, Quote $quote)
    {
        $result = $proceed($quote);

        if ($result) {
            $city = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
            if (in_array(strtolower($city), self::$cities)) return false;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    static $cities = [ // the cities to be excluded
        'austin',
        'new york',
        'boston'
    ];
}
```

And you'd have this in `{module_dir}/etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplug" type="Your\Module\Plugin\CashondeliveryPlug" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: where should i place this code?

Comment: In my project there is no isAvailable function in cashondelivery.php file.but instead this function is situated in AbstractMethod.php file

Comment: Yes, `Cashondelivery` inherits the method from `AbstractMethod`. You should follow a tutorial on how to create a module and use this code in your module. The only files I haven't given you are `registration.php` and `etc/module.xml` which are the boilerplate module declaration files.

Comment: thanks Aaron. And i'm really new to magento. Can you plz guide me to place this code, if you don't mind?

Comment: There's plenty of good tutorials explaining how to create a module (http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) - do that first. Assuming you have a module, you'd then put the code in `{your_module}/Plugin/CashondeliveryPlug.php` and `{your_module}/etc/di.xml}`.

Comment: How to check `getShippingMethod()` and disable COD?

Comment: I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716