# Magento 2: Disable "Cash on delivery" for downloadable products

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1, payment-methods

I need to disable the CoD payment method for carts with downloadable products. I started working on **a plugin, but got hung up on this - have no idea how to get product types from cart**.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/08/an-easy-way-to-remove-a-payment-method-in-magento-2/ from Quote Items getProductType of getTypeId

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best idea to use **event/observer** concept.

Fire ***an observer on event***: `payment_method_is_active`.

**Observer:**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[Modulename]]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverforDisabledCod implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if ($quote === null || $method_instance->getCode() != 'cashondelivery')
            return;

        /* Disable All payment gateway exclude Your payment Gateway */
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $eachitem) {
            if ($eachitem->getProductType() == 'downloadable') {
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amit! Any ideas on disabling CoD for select shipping methods? :)

Comment: ya.. it possaible. you already get  quote object at this observer then you can get selected ship,ment

Comment: I need `getShippingMethod()`. How to get it?

Comment: I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716

Comment: cool, .........

Answer (score 2):

Didn't work for me, needed to make the following changes:

1. Replaced `$result->isAvailable = false;` with `$result->setData('is_available', false);`
2. Replaced `$items= as $eachitem` with `$items as $eachitem`

(magento 2.1.7)