# disable credit card based on product

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods

I'm using OnTap extension [Extension Link](https://marketplace.magento.com/ontap-module-mastercard.html) with magento 2.

I want to disable this payment based on product. After searching I found tutoriales like [Magento 2: How to show/hide payment method on basis of amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/magento-2-how-to-show-hide-payment-method-on-basis-of-amount?rq=1) but all of them not work with me. any Ideas please

Comment: I also try this [Magento 2: Disable “Cash on delivery” for downloadable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154155/magento-2-disable-cash-on-delivery-for-downloadable-products/154158) , but without any succes