# Magento 2 disable COD payment method on checkout from observer

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment-methods

I need to disable COD option from observer, For observer my code is:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  { 
  $order= $observer->getData('order');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote(); 
$QuoteData = $quote->getItemsCollection(); 
$checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

    foreach($QuoteData as $data) {   
             $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
            $p = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($data['product_id']);
            $attribute = $p->getResource()->getAttribute('cod'); 
            if ($attribute) 
            { 
                  $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($p);

                    if($attr_value == 'Yes' || $attr_value == 'yes' || $attr_value == 'YES'){ return;
                        $code = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
                             if($code == "cashondelivery" || $code == "mpcashondelivery"){

                             $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page

                            }
                    }  
            }
        }


  }
```

But COD is not disabling if anyone have solution please share.

Comment: what is your event name?

Comment: payment_method_is_active, I am disabling COD for specific products which have attribute value cod == Yes

Comment: maybe there is some clue on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154158/46716 post

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with Plugin. I too found an issue while getting the quote through observer way. Try to implement it by Plugin. The below code is working fine for me.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Module">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="restrictByCustomer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Method\Module\Available"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Payment/Method/Module/Available.php**

```
public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, $result)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $paymentMethodCode = $subject->getCode();

    if ($paymentMethodCode == 'cod') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;  //Return result for true scenario. return true wont work
    }
}
```

However, if you still want to do it with Observer only, try to get quote by following way,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
```

Note: I do not recommend to use object manager.

Answer (score 0):

***$QuoteData***  does not give  you the  Quote items.
But `$QuoteData->getAllItems()` given the quote items.

So,

`foreach($QuoteData as $data) {`  is wrong code

**it Should be**

```
foreach ($QuoteData->getAllItems() as $item) { 

    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
            continue;
    }
```

Also, you should  remove `$order= $observer->getData('order');` at `payment_method_is_active` event  you cannot get Order oBject