# Magento2: How to get shipping method in order using observer `sales_order_save_after`?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping-methods

I want to get shipping method in my observer after placing an order. I am using `sales_order_save_after` event, so after place an order I want to get shipping method. I am getting shipping description but that is not enough for me. I want shipping method only but it's not returning `shipping_method` in response.

Please help me how to get shipping method in this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the shipping method by

```
$order->getShippingMethod();
```

or

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```

Comment: it's not working. Are you sure ? I am using `sales_order_place_after` event , in that it's not returning shipping method. Is there any other way ?

Comment: try `$order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()`

Comment: $order->getShippingMethod(); is working. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer`  and `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();` ? I get `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getShippingMethod() on null`

Comment: I use `payment_method_is_active` event to disable payment method.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716

Comment: how can i get only shipping method name without title ?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR What event used for getting shipping methods before place an order  magento 1.9?

Answer (score 7):

```
$order->getShippingDescription(); // returns Shipping Method Title
```