# how to get shipping method using order id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, object-manager

I am trying to get the shipping method using `Object Manager`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);
```

by doing var_dump on `$order->getShippingAddress()->getData()` i get no such thing as shipping method, from where i can get shipping method?
I am new to magento.

after referring to this link

> [Magento2: How to get shipping method in order using observer `sales_order_save_after`?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155279/magento2-how-to-get-shipping-method-in-order-using-observer-sales-order-save-a)

I don't know how to use sales_order_save_after if that's the only solution out there.

Comment: It is not necessary to use `sales_order_save_after` event to print the shipping method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to get shipping method.

```
$shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
$order->getShippingMethod();
```

It's getting the shipping method. Still facing any issue let me know.

Comment: it prints data correctly but it has extra strings also which is useless, `string(20) "Free Ground Shipping"` string(20), so i am assuming getShippingDescription() gives arrray, i can access it using its array index key also which is table's column name
how to do i kind that index key

Comment: You can getting shipping method code using $order->getShippingMethod(); this.

Comment: thanks `$shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();` works for me

Answer (score 1):

You are doing var_dump on `$order->getShippingAddress()->getData()`. Instead of that, do var_dump on `$order->getData()` and you will be able to see `shipping_method`.

You can get the shipping method by

```
$order->getShippingMethod();
```

or

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```

Comment: $order->getShippingMethod(); gives "freeshipping_freeshipping" and but i want "Free Ground Shipping" so $order->getShippingDescription(); works  for me
what's the difference between these two

Comment: Don't do this it will hang you browser even pc [var_dump($order->getData())]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an observer

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<event name="sales_order_save_before">
    <observer name="order_save_after" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\OrderSaveAfter" />
</event>
```

> OrderSaveAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->getShippingMethod();
    }
}
```