# How to remove payment method step in checkout process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

I have magento Open Source 2.3.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now. How to remove payment method step in checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

Any suggestion welcome in advanced.

Below is the exact representation of the requirement.
[image]

Comment: pls check this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188334/how-to-programatically-disable-a-payment-method-at-checkout-magento-2

Comment: Hi jafar, thanks for the suggestion. but my question is different. i need to skip the entire payment method step process. Please refer this magento 1 solution link: https://www.milople.com/blogs/magento/remove-payment-method-step-checkout-process.html . I have mentioned magento 1 link. the same solution i am looking for magento 2. if you know please help.