# How to remove the product price for the order summary section in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3, order-summary

Only i need to show the number of quantity items in the Order Summary.

if any one know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure. since i'm new to magento.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Order Summary screenshot:

[image: magento]

Comment: Means you need to remove only price from order summary?

Comment: yes. only i need to show the product name and number of quantity items.

Comment: okay working for you

Comment: Uploaded answer for you. let me know it's working for you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to override `subtotal.html` file in your theme under :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal.html

and remove or comment whole code of `subtotal.html` file

run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean && php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you Naresh. its working fine.

Comment: if you know the answer for this question.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295168/how-to-remove-payment-method-step-in-checkout-process-in-magento-2-3-2 . please answer. It is very helpful for me.