# Hide COD and Check/Money order for specific shipping methods

Tags: payment-methods, shipping-methods, magento2.1.6

Please advise how to use the current solution in order to hide the COD and also the Check/Money Order for some shipping methods? Magento 2.1.6 CE

[Previous question relative to this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108594/magento-2-enable-cash-on-delivery-only-for-specific-shipment-method)

Comment: You can try to implement juhanix solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189530/46716 It has worked for me, but I needed to disable only COD.