# Magento 2: Which event get called when selecting shipping method on checkout?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I build a custom shipping method and i want to hide "cash on delivery" payment method based on my shipping method selection. I am assuming that one possible way to write the code in observer and set the "is_available"= false for that payment method. But i am not sure whether is there any event get called when user choose the shipping method on checkout

Answer (score 2):

SR/Stackexchange/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin_frontend" type="SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model\MethodList" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

SR/Stackexchange/Plugin/Model/MethodList.php

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Model;

class MethodList
{
    public function afterGetAvailableMethods(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject,
        $availableMethods,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethod($quote);
        foreach ($availableMethods as $key => $method) {
            // change logic here
            if(($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery') && ($shippingMethod == 'flatrate_flatrate')) {
                unset($availableMethods[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $availableMethods;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return string
     */
    private function getShippingMethod($quote)
    {
        if($quote) {
            return $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Will be called every time when the user select the shipping method  ?

Comment: I tried your solution but after using your code my checkout page become blank. Can you please add more details how it works ?

Comment: Do you use magento default checkout? It's working fine for M2.2.4. If you select shipping method in shipping page, then click next. In payment &  review section will restrict your payment method.

Comment: I am using Aheadworks Onestep Checkout.

Comment: I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108594/magento-2-enable-cash-on-delivery-only-for-specific-shipment-method/189530#189530 and this worked for me perfectly.

Comment: It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if magento has any event which triggers when the shipping method is selected. 
One solution is to create plugin on `saveAddressInformation` function of `Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement` and use `after` method inside which you can implement your logic.