# Magento 2 - plugin error - enable cash on delivery only for specific shipment method

Tags: magento2, cash-on-delivery

I created the plugin for different payment methods by following [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108594/magento-2-enable-cash-on-delivery-only-for-specific-shipment-method/250942).

It works fine, but it has an error.

When you want to change to another shipping method, if you previously had a payment method selected and this is disabled by the plugin, it's enabled and duplicated.

Also, it doesn't load correctly, since it gives an error with javascript and doesn't load the method completely.

[image: it doesn't load correctly]

[image: error with javascript]

This 2nd failure is given even if you don't select any payment method previously

If they can review it, it's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create `cashondelivery-method.js` on following path

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer

Add following code in that file

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/payment/cashondelivery'
            },

            /** Returns payment method instructions */
            getInstructions: function() {

                if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions != 'undefined')
                {
                    return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now run setup upgrade and content deployment command.